# Converting 3 prong plug to turnlock plug

Tags: electrical, receptacle

I recently purchased a jet dust collector which is 230v motor 15amps. However, its plug is the regular 3 prong plug. In my garage, I have a separate 250v outlet with 20amps circuit breaker but it has the lockturn outlet. Is there a way to convert this 3 prong plug to the turnlock using an adapter? or should I cut the 3 prongs and install turnlock plug? Thank you [image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Changing the plug is very safe since there is no way for it to have power when changing.  Changing the outlet will keep everything looking neat, just make sure there is no power, turn off the breaker and double check at outlet before finding power with your fingers.  Been there, done that(wrong breaker).

Answer (score 5):

> However, its plug is the regular 3 prong plug

Well, it's a regular NEMA 6-15 plug, which is a bit of an oddity.  Here's the whole lineup.

[image]

Notice that the 6-20 has a T-shape so it is downward compatible with the 6-15.  (you probably know NEMA 5-20s do the same).

So you are perfectly welcome to replace that with a simplex (1-socket) or duplex NEMA 6-20.

You cannot install a simplex NEMA 6-15 for the reasons covered [in this answer here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/269505/running-a-nema-6-15-plug-off-double-pole-20a-breaker). But a duplex 6-15 is fine.

Comment: This is such a delightful corner case. The 'right' way to do this is to install a duplex 6-15, duplex 6-20, or simple 6-20. That meets code and works. But it would be just as safe to change out the plug on the dust collector for a twist-lock, even though it's not the 'right' way to do it. Lots of ways to properly solve this.

Comment: Hi Thank you. I found this plug, I assume this will work since its 20amps https://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-20-Amp-250-Volt-Locking-Plug-Black-and-White-R50-02321-0CS/300862089#overlay

Comment: @Sam whatever your comfort level is.  The straight-blade sockets are cheaper than that plug.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up ordering this off amazon. https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B08CXFL1Q4

Comment: Check to make sure it actually has a UL marking and a real file number when it shows up. Amazon is known for listing a whole lot of garbage-tier junk, at least when it comes to electrical parts.

Comment: The claimed "E855464" UL file number appears to be faked. It does not show up in the UL Product iQ database. https://productiq.ulprospector.com/en/search?term=E855464

Comment: @Sam -- please just *don't* bother ordering electrical stuff off Amazon (or eBay, or anywhere else connected to the Cheese pipeline for that matter)

Comment: I was able to confirmed that their UL is real. The UL on the plug is registered here. productiq.ulprospector.com/en/search?term=E355464. I replaced the plug and the dust collector turned on! I'm happy.